# php copy and paste files on server? move files on server?

Tags: php, ftp

I was wondering how possible it is with PHP to copy a file from one directory on a server and paste it into another. I have a system that when a user registers creates a sub directory called the same as there username, I then want to copy a file called profile.php from a sub directory called users and paste it in the new directory with the name of the user?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: PHP `copy()` function.

However, your design seems bad. Are you sure that's the only way?

Comment: @pimvdb post that as an answer so it can be upvoted

Comment: You are dynamically creating a profile.php for each user?  Why not have a central profile.php that changes based on the users info in a database, and then redirect to that file when someone hits your users-sub-dir/profile.php?

Comment: well creating a directory called the same as the users username creates a user profile so they can access a profile page, the profile.php page populates the profile with all the relevant information. Having each user with their own directory makes it possible to access profiles like www.website.com/myname will link to their profile. Its the only way I know how to acheive user profiles

Comment: these directories should be virtual ones as well. use mod_rewrite

Comment: how could I redirect to that single file when they access the subdirectory?

Comment: I suggest you look into the front controller pattern.  That is when you have a single index.php that basically decides where all requests go.  It works in conjunction with URL rewriting (e.g., Apache mod_rewrite directives in .htaccess).  Google "php front controller" to find out more.

Answer (score 6):

## You shouldn't do it this way.

There must be just **one** profile.php, serving all users. 
That's the way how PHP works. It is used to create *dynamical* sites, producing dynamical content based on user's input.

So, based on entered username, it should display particular user's info. One script to serve all users.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP `copy()` function just copies a file from one directory to another.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 0):

As Col. Shrapnel suggest, you shouldn't copy the profile.php for each user. That will be hard to maintain, and unnecessary duplication. But here's how you can make subdirectories for each of your users.

```
<?php

    $username = 'me';

    if(userregisters) {
    mkdir('/file/to/path/{$username}');
    }
```

Comment: I already have a sub directory for each user, but without copying the relevant files into the subdirectory it will be empty, the files that need to be copied will populate the user profile page